# How to esttab when treatment variables has different names

Tags: stata

I am running a dynamic DiD in Stata. I have to check the robustness of the geographical size of my treatment area and for that I run regressions where I interact the year with a treatment variable. Like this:

For a 30 km treatment area

```
quietly reg infl ib2015.year##treat30km i.year i.examcode i.NSEGbin i.schoolid, cluster(schoolid)
eststo modelDiD8
```

For a 20 km treatment area

```
quietly reg infl ib2015.year##treat20km i.year i.examcode i.NSEGbin i.schoolid, cluster(schoolid)
eststo modelDiD7
```

The problem is that the regressions yield different interactions coefficients, for example: 2010.year#1.**treat30km** vs 2010.year#1.**treat20km** and hence using `esttab` the table doesn't show the coefficients in the same line, which is undesirable.

I have tried using a local macro `treat` in hope that Stata could identify the interactions in multiple regressions as the same: however, Stata prints the actual name and not the macro.

Answer (score 1):

In `esttab`, you have the option `rename`, that you can use as

> rename(2010.year#1.treat30km newname 2010.year#1.treat20km newname)

Comment: I guess you need two different new names.